# Trying to create a select element using database values in a react-redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm returning a set of text values from a database table and then trying to create a select element from them. I get the following error msg:

- Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

I create a local store with the values in an array titled categories:

```
let categoriesFromApi = fetchedCategories.map(category => {
    return { key: category, value: category, display: category }
})
this.setState({ categories: [{ key: 0, value: '', display: '(Select A Category)' }].concat(categoriesFromApi) });
```

and then I build the select element:

```
<select value="Select a Category"
    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ selectedCategory: e.target.value, validationError: e.target.value === "" ? "You must select a Category" : "" })}>
    {this.state.categories.map((category) => <option value={category.category}>{category.category}</option>)}
</select>
```

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Keys help React identify which items have changed (added/removed/re-ordered). To give a unique identity to every element inside the array, a key is required.

In your case you can do something like below:

{this.state.categories.map((category, index) => <option key={`${category.category}-${index}`} value={category.category}>{category.category}</option>)}

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<select
    value="Select a Category"
    onChange={e =>
        this.setState({
            selectedCategory: e.target.value,
            validationError:
                e.target.value === "" ? "You must select a Category" : ""
        })
    }
>
    {this.state.categories.map((category, idx) => (
        <option key={`${category.id}-${idx}`} value={category.category}>
            {category.category}
        </option>
    ))}
</select>;
```

Answer (score 0):

wasn't selecting the right items from the category:

simplified the assignment:

```
this.setState({ categories: fetchedCategories });
```

then:

```
<select value="Select a Category"
    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ selectedCategory: e.target.value, validationError: e.target.value === "" ? "You must select a Category" : "" })}>
    {this.state.categories.map((category) => <option value={category.cat_item}>{category.cat_item}</option>)}
</select>
```